# Regarding breaking up fast

Tags: sawm

If a person becomes seriously sick while fasting and suffers extreme pain, can the fast be broken up immediately?
The person I know is schizophrenic and dumb. His parents force him to fast. He threatens people and calls police and pretends to be the king of the world.
Is fasting compulsory for him?

Comment: Without his medicines he becomes aggressive

Comment: We are not a fatwa site and this requires additional details. It may be possible to take the medication at sahr and iftar and avoid taking it during the fast.

Answer (score -1):

1. You cannot fast if you are seriously ill. See for example [here](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa/8535).
   Scolars are completely unanimous on this.
2. Mentally handicapped persons are not requested to fulfil the common duties. See [here](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/fatwaa-dot-com/20866).